# Read octet stream in C Program

Tags: c

I would like to read an octet-stream in my C code. Example of output (it's docker API log output):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 20:09:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

▒2015-05-13T20:09:06.335126685Z 2015-05-13 20:09:06 ERROR AppException: <traceback>
```

My code:

```
char *message = NULL;
char buffer[buffer_size+1];
while ((nbytes = read(sock, buffer, buffer_size)) > 0 )
{
    buffer[nbytes] = 0;
    message = realloc(message, (strlen(message) + nbytes + 1));
    strcat(message, buffer);
}
log(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "message: %s", message);
```

But I'm able to read only headers (debug output of message variable):

```
▒w▒WHTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 May 2015 20:14:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

How can I read content of response? 
Can the non-ASCII character in response be a problem? 
Another Docker API responses (inspect, info, ps) doesn't have this issue.

Comment: `char *message = NULL; ...strlen(message)` is a problem.

Comment: An octet is just a collection of eight adjascent bits. This is often called a byte, allthought this is not correct (a byte might have more or less bits actually). So an "octet stream" is just a stream of octets without know meaning to the system. If you want to read one, just use normal binary read. Once you are interpreting the data, however, it has a structure and would not be a mere octet stream anymore.

Comment: Also, you should not use string functions on input from sockets (not only on binary data) - the stream might contain zero bytes that are treated as string terminators, OR it might not have zero bytes at all, so your calls to string functions will result in corrupted memory.

Comment: @JanGaraj I have exactly the same issue. I am trying to read the response content of an API that has application/octet-stream as content-type. This Flask API sends back a numpy array and I am trying to read this array in C. In Python clients, I am simply doing np.frombuffer(response), but in C I don't know what to do. The response, in C, only has the headers plus 8 more characters. How can I convert these 8 characters to an array of floats?